# Option clash for package [square]{natbib}

Tags: natbib, option-clash

If I call `natbib`, LaTeX runs with no problem. However, if I had the following

```
\usepackage[square, comma, numbers, sort&compress, super]{natbib}
```

it does not run and the following error appears:

```
Latex Error: Option clash for package natbib
```

The complete beginning of the document is:

```
\documentclass[preprint,showpacs,preprintnumbers,showkeys]{revtex4}

\newcommand{\classoption}[1]{\texttt{#1}}   
\newcommand{\macro}[1]{\texttt{\textbackslash#1}}  
\newcommand{\m}[1]{\macro{#1}}  
\newcommand{\env}[1]{\texttt{#1}}  

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{epstopdf}  
\usepackage{bm}  
\usepackage{color}  
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[square,                                                     
comma,                                                                              
numbers,                                                                            
sort&compress,                                                              
super]{natbib}  
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}  
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts}  
\usepackage[hang,scriptsize,tight]{subfigure}  

\begin{document}
```

Comment: This happens when a package you try to use is required by another package or your class, but with different options. You can try `\PassOptionsToPackage{<option>}{<package>}`.

Comment: Add the options to those for `\documentclass`; but I doubt the journal editors will be happy to see such changes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Instead of (re)loading the `natbib` package with various options, simply execute

```
\usepackage{natbib}
\setcitestyle{square, comma, numbers,sort&compress, super}
```

By the way, the options `numbers` and `super` and mutually exclusive: choose one or the other, *but not both*.

Comment: Read your comment to my answer :-)

Comment: Thank you :). Now it does run with no clash error. Unfortunately it does not do what I thought it would. I want to have superscript citations with square brackets (wikipedia style) but now im a bit lost on how to do it. Maybe you can help me again :)

Comment: @joaofilipehortabelodasilv - To generate numeric superscript-style call-outs surrounded by square brackets, don't specify the option `numbers`.

Comment: Dear @Mico Thank you :) Now, it is almost working good: they already appear as superscripts, however they are not surrounded by square brackets as I need. Im sorry to bother you again but if you can tell me what else could I do, it would be great. At the moment I have something like this:

Comment: \documentclass[preprint,showpacs,preprintnumbers,showkeys{revtex4}
\usepackage{natbib}
\setcitestyle{super,comma,sort&compress,square}
\newcommand{\classoption}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\newcommand{\macro}[1]{\texttt{\textbackslash#1}}
\newcommand{\m}[1]{\macro{#1}}
\newcommand{\env}[1]{\texttt{#1}}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

Comment: @Mico to be simpler. Just this below matters I think. \documentclass[preprint,showpacs,preprintnumbers,showkeys{revtex4}
\usepackage{natbib}
\setcitestyle{super,comma,sort&compress,square}

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether this gives the desired results, but the following will compile without the option-clash:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{square,comma,numbers,sort&compress,super}{natbib}
\documentclass[preprint,showpacs,preprintnumbers,showkeys]{revtex4}

\newcommand{\classoption}[1]{\texttt{#1}}   
\newcommand{\macro}[1]{\texttt{\textbackslash#1}}  
\newcommand{\m}[1]{\macro{#1}}  
\newcommand{\env}[1]{\texttt{#1}}  

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{epstopdf}  
\usepackage{bm}  
\usepackage{color}  
%\usepackage{natbib}
%\usepackage[square,                                                     
%comma,                                                                              
%numbers,                                                                            
%sort&compress,                                                              
%super]{natbib}  
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}  
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts}  
\usepackage[hang,scriptsize,tight]{subfigure}  

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}  
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! As I said above, unfortunately it does not do what I thought it would. I want to have superscript citations with square brackets (wikipedia style) but now im a bit lost on how to do it. Maybe you guys can help me again

Answer (score 2):

`revtex4` itself already loads `natbib`. The reason why you should pass the options before `documentclass` to `natbib`

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{square,comma,numbers,sort&compress,super}{natbib}  
\documentclass[preprint,showpacs,preprintnumbers,showkeys]{revtex4}

\newcommand{\classoption}[1]{\texttt{#1}}   
\newcommand{\macro}[1]{\texttt{\textbackslash#1}}  
\newcommand{\m}[1]{\macro{#1}}  
\newcommand{\env}[1]{\texttt{#1}}  

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{epstopdf}  
\usepackage{bm}  
\usepackage{color}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}  
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts}  
\usepackage[hang,scriptsize,tight]{subfigure}  

\begin{document} 
foo
\end{document}
```

Comment: For the sake of good housekeeping, should the lone `\usepackage{natbib}` be deleted (or commented out) as well? Separately, I'd put in a note to exhort the OP not to specify mutually exclusive options, such as `numbers` and `super`. He/she should set one or the other option, but not both...

Comment: Thanks Mico, I deleted the line, it was by mistake there. I do not use natbib, so I leave it to the user to use the right optional arguments

Comment: Thank you very much! As I said above, unfortunately it does not do what I thought it would. I want to have superscript citations with square brackets (wikipedia style) but now im a bit lost on how to do it. Maybe you guys can help me again