# How to change the citation to number style instead of author-date (please see the screenshot)?

Tags: miktex, texstudio

[image]

I am using a thesis template that I downloaded from internet. I am using natbib style for "reference" section. After compiling, I am getting author-year format. But I would like to have in "number" format written in square ([]) bracket. I have tried a few discussions such as

1. [Option clash for package [square]{natbib}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367391/option-clash-for-package-squarenatbib)

and when errors came,

2. [Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations. ...mand\NAT@force@numbers{}\NAT@force@numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/414018/package-natbib-error-bibliography-not-compatible-with-author-year-citations?rq=1)

But finally I am not getting the "[]" type reference.

My minimum working frame as follows;

```
 % Thesis framework file.
%\PassOptionsToPackage{square,comma,numbers,sort&compress,super}{natbib}
\documentclass[11pt]{iitkgpthesis}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\setcitestyle{square, comma, numbers,sort&compress, super}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}

% Frontmatter. Add other pages as needed.
\pagenumbering{roman}
 \include{firstpage}
 \include{frontmatter}
% \include{abstract}
 \cleardoublepage
 \tableofcontents
 \include{listofnotation}
 \cleardoublepage
 \listoftables
 \listoffigures
 \cleardoublepage

% Main thesis section

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\input{Introduction}        %%Chapter 1%%

\newpage

%\input{Materialia}  %%Chapter 2%%

%\input{Workch-0}   %%Chapter 3%% 

%\input{Workch-1}   %%Chapter 4%%

%\input{Workch-2}   %%Chapter 5%%

%\input{Workch-3}   %%Chapter 6%%

%\input{Workch-4}   %%Chapter 7%%

% \input{litrev} 

% \input{formu}

% \input{probdef}

% \input{result}

%\include{Overall Summary and Conclusions}

\cleardoublepage

% A file for citations not appearing in the document itself.

% \input{nocites}
% 
\singlespacing

\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}

\bibliography{RSC}

% If you have no appendices, remove the following two lines.
% If you have more appdences, add them as necessary.
% \appendix
% \include{apdxa}

\end{document}
```

\chapter{Introduction}

\subsection{Literature review}

(example chapter portion) Herein, phase inversion poly(vinylidene fluoride)/poly(methyl methacrylate) (PVDF/PMMA) microporous membranes were prepared at various PMMA concentration by immersion precipitation method. Increment in the PMMA concentration has a significant influence in the PVDF membrane crystallinity, which is studied by differential scanning calorimeter, X‐ray diffractometer, and small‐angle X‐ray scattering analyses. Properties such as membrane bulk structure, porosity, hydrophilicity, mechanical stability, and water flux vary in terms of PMMA concentration. Porosity is increased, and tensile strength decreased when PMMA concentration is beyond 30 wt %. Thermodynamic instability during the liquid to solid phase separation and variation in the crystallinity has an intense effect on these membrane properties. Then, 70/30 blend membrane selected as optimum composition owing to the high porosity and pure water flux compared to other compositions. This membrane is modified with a composite filler derived from the graphene oxide and titanate crosslinked by chitosan. The antibacterial, antifouling, and bovine serum albumin separation studies reveal that the developed nanocomposite membrane is a potential candidate for the separation application.

Comment: Since that class is not well known you probably need to provide a link to that as well. Additionally this MWE is not self contained as we don't have the file you include. Please provide a self contained example that others can test as is.

Comment: I downloaded the template from one google grp discussion, https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vipes2011/vKcua6SYVXA
If it is not working I shall try with thesis class, which I find it yesterday.